# Sharepoint BCS .net assembly connector: how to access filter params in finder method passed in via an OData request

Tags: sharepoint, odata, bcs

Is there a way to access the OData formulated filter parameters from a request targetting an external list?

I have a BCS entity with a finder and a specific finder implemented. I also have [in] parameter defined for the finder method as well filter rules in the BCS model definition. BCS filter is bound to the [in] parameter.

The setup works when I access this from an external list and a configured aspx view (the filter is visible in the config screens and passes the param to the finder method). However when I try to access the list over OData the parameter received by the finder method is empty.

This is how I access the list with OData: `http://<mysharepoint>/_api/web/lists/myexternalList/items?$filter=param eq 'value'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no option for this in SharePoint 2013. You can process the query string manually, this is the only way.